# Create FedAuth cookie from SecurityToken

Tags: .net, sharepoint, adfs

What I want to do is to login to sharepoint site (it uses ADFS server) using HttpWebRequest.
How I am doing it:

1. I have obtained SecurityToken using WSTrustChannelFactory (see this post [here](http://leandrob.com/2012/04/requesting-a-token-from-adfs-2-0-using-ws-trust-with-username-and-password/))
2. Converting SecurityToken into FedAuth cookie
3. Creating HttpWebRequest and attaching FedAuth cookie.
4. Sending the HttpWebRequest request and receiving response.

**PROBLEM**: in step 2 I need to convert SecurityToken (which is '_a9e1657d-9360-4578-9075-9a84617a6826') into FedAuth cookie, which should be something like '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'

It seems cookie value is encrypted. 
How to create encrypted cookie from token string? Does anybody know?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am faced with a similar problem of trying to obtain a FedAuth Cookie from my local SharePoint 2013 server [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339348/how-to-obtain-fedauth-cookie-from-on-premise-sharepoint-2013-and-adfs)

Answer (score 0):

I found an example that parses a security token and decrypts it using local store certificates. Then will produce the FedAuth Cookie and attempt to log you in to a sharepoint instance using the CSOM. [Example](http://blog.skadefro.dk/2011/09/claims-authentication-made-simple.html?showComment=1408438409787#c1996835031105089814)

However, I am still getting an error when logging into Sharepoint, but it seems to be do to certificate name mistmatch.